# Is it possible to open tabs in existing window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Let's say there is a page behind a login system that I would like to run puppeteer for web automation and for simplicity, I don't want to launch a new browser and enter the login system with puppeteer. Instead, I want puppeteer to activate the tab where I've manually logged in to the system.

I found something like page.bringToFront() but it works for pages, not windows/browser.
This leads me to the question: Is it possible to open tabs in existing window with puppeteer?

Comment: Yes, once you login just reuse the same browser instance to create a new page object. That'll automatically have the cookies/session/whatever you need to stay logged in.

Comment: Look for [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener)